# zsh: command not found: mockgen - golang 1.18 - macOS Monterrey

Tags: go, zsh, gomock

I'm new to go. Currently I'm using zsh terminal in macOS, just followed the instructions pointed out here https://github.com/golang/mock when installing go mock. However when trying to execute a mockgen command I keep seeing `zsh: command not found: mockgen` and when navigating in the terminal to my `$GOPATH/bin` i see mockgen inthere, so I don't know if there's anything else needed.

[image]

These are the variables I have configured in my /.zshrc file:

```
#GO path
export GOPATH="$HOME/Documents/study_projects/go"
export GOBINPATH="$GOPATH/bin"
```

Idk if `GOBINPATH` is a proper name for this `$GOPATH/bin` variable to be exported to the PATH also, aso pointed out in https://github.com/golang/mock (mockgen/gomock)  installation instructions. Does anyone of you know what else is needed here, do I need an additional configuration for this mockgen command to work with zsh?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you set PATH? Like: export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Make sure run below for go 1.16+

   go install github.com/golang/mock/mockgen@v1.6.0
2. Add **users/[your_login]/go/bin** to .zshrc path

Answer (score 12):

add `export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin` in .zshrc and try again.

Comment: And remember to `source .zshrc`, maybe you also need to reload your terminal.

Comment: you can add `alias load="source ~/.zshrc"` in your `~/.zshrc` file, then each time you make change in the file you can update terminal with `load` command without restarting a terminal

Answer (score 2):

What version of Golang are you using? For Go version 1.16+, you don't need to use `GOPATH`
In my case, the binary was installed in this path: `/Users/USERNAME/go/bin/mockgen` so I added it to my `$PATH` in `.zshrc`.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

My mockgen got installed under vim /Users/xxx/go/bin/darwin_amd64/ instead of  /Users/xxx/go/bin so I moved it to bin folder and it worked!

```
cp /Users/xxx/go/bin/darwin_amd64/mockgen /Users/xxx/go/bin/
```

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. Tried to add `mockgen` to the `$PATH`, didn't help.

Just added the path directly in command line:

`/Users/{username}/go/bin/mockgen -source={source_path}.go -destination={destination_path}.go -package=mock {interfaces}`

Worked for me